# Where should the uwsgi_params file be located and what is its extension?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how this file works. I seem to see it in every example. See below:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sivusto3.fi;
  access_log /var/log/customersite3/access_log;
  location / {
    root /var/www/customersite3;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3033;
    include uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[*uwsgi_params* file](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html#what-is-the-uwsgi-params-file) is located inside Nginx directory (`/etc/nginx` on my Linux machine)

```
me:~$ ls /etc/nginx | grep uwsgi
uwsgi_params
```

and has no extension.